# I can't initial Google Cloud Platform data lab even I config VPC network to listen in port 8081

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, google-cloud-datalab

I try to initial datalab in google cloud platform The error code inform me that the port 8081 need to be open
[image]
I go back to VPC networking and configure the port on this vpc network but the datalab is not initialize.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be directly related with [this issue](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1973).
It says:

> You can fix that by using gcloud to SSH in and then running:
>
> `sudo chown -R datalab /home/datalab`
>
> I do not know of any scenario that would cause the /home/datalab
>   folder to be owned by an account associated with the user who created
>   the instance, so I do not know how this instance could have gotten
>   into that state, but running the chown command above should fix it.